# Form builder for a related entity Symfony 3

Tags: symfony-3.4

Well let's say I have 2 entities:

1. category
2. product

I want to create a form builder for the entity product in which there is a select to choose the category of the product.

How can I do that with Symfony 3.4?

Can you guys give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [EntityType](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

See below for an example:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
// ...

->add('category', EntityType::class, [
    'class'         => 'AppBundle:Category',
    'multiple'      => false,
    'expanded'      => false,
    'choice_label'  => 'title',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        // use query builder for ordering/filtering choices
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('cat')
            ->orderBy('cat.title', 'ASC');
    },
])
```

I assume your category entity has a property called `title`. This would be in your `Product` form type class.